# Getting unexpected error while sorting the drop down value using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am getting some error  while sorting my drop down value alphabetically using Angular.js. I am providing my code below:

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example16data | orderBy:'label'" selected-model="example16model" checkboxes="true" extra-settings="example16settings" class="form-control"></div>

 angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
      var data={'label':obj.cat_name+':'+obj.subcat_name,'id':obj.subcat_id};
      $scope.example16data.push(data);
 })
```

Here I am using Anguar's `angularjs-dropdown-multiselect` for drop down list but when I am trying to sorting the list I am getting the following unexpected error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2C%5Cr%5Cnd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2C%5Cr%5Cnd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2C%5Cr%5Cnd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2C%5Cr%5Cnd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2C%5Cr%5Cnd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ABEER%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A341%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3ACOCKTAILS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A342%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22DRINKS%3AWINE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2251%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A343%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AAPPETIZERS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A344%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABREAKFAST%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A345%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ABRUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A346%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ACHINESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A347%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AGREEK%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A348%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AINDIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A349%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AITALIAN%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A350%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALATE%20NIGHT%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A351%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ALUNCH%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A352%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3APIZZA%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A353%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASEAFOOD%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2244%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A354%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ASUSHI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3ATHAI%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A356%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AVIETNAMESE%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A357%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22FOOD%3AWINGS%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A358%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22HAPPY%20HOUR%3AHAPPY%20HOUR%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%5D
    at angularjs.js:6
    at n.$digest (angularjs.js:131)
    at n.$apply (angularjs.js:133)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (multipledropdown.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
(anonymous) @ angularjs.js:6
$digest @ angularjs.js:131
$apply @ angularjs.js:133
(anonymous) @ multipledropdown.js:1
dispatch @ jquery.js:4670
r.handle @ jquery.js:4338
```

Here I need to sort the drop down value alphabetically order.

Comment: If you can provide fiddler/plunker then it would great.

Comment: Infinite digest loop: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: I have also seen this but how to resolve it ?

Comment: Try removing the .push() from the loop, and add all the values at once after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a $timeout function itself from your code then only we can avoid the digest looping in Angularjs.

```
You can remove your orderBy in HTML and apply the bellow login to the 
 controller. 
$scope.$example16data = $filter("orderBy")($scope.example16data, 
"label")
```

Comment: Where you are using the `$timeout` in this example code ? This example also throwing same error.

Comment: Hi @satya we can go some other alternative idea. Because of "ng-dropdown-multiselect" rebind on every iteration.  You can orderBy apply into the controller itself. $scope.example16data = $filter("orderBy")($scope.example16data, "label")